# Pass variable from java script function to java class

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring

I working with STS.
I build application that contain html file - java script
in this file there is function that configure variables.
attached:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
    <head>
        <title>Help Desk</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to help Desk!</h1>
        <p>Please fill in the fields...</p>

        <form>
            <div><label> User Name:</label> <input type="text" name="username"/> </div>
            <div><label>.             .</label></div>
            <div><label> Email:</label> <input type="email" name="email"/> </div>
            <div><label>.             .</label></div>
            <div><label> Subject of the request:</label>  
                <select name="selectSubject">
                  <option value="IT">IT</option>
                  <option value="HardWare">HardWare</option>
                  <option value="Salary">Salary</option>
                  <option value="Report hours">Report hours</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div><label>.             .</label></div>
            <div><label> Your message:</label> <input name="yourMessage" type="text"/> </div>
            <div><label>.             .</label></div>
            <div><label>.             .</label></div>
        </form>

        <button style="width:200px; height:50px; bottom font: bold; color:red; " onclick="sendRequest()">Send request</button>

        <script>
        function sendRequest() {

            userName = document.forms[0].elements["username"].value;
            email = document.forms[0].elements["email"].value;
            subject = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[0].value;
            message = document.forms[0].elements["yourMessage"].value;

            detailes = userName + ";" + email + ";" + subject + ";" + message + ";";

            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = document.applets[0].getStringJava();
        }
        </script>
        <p id="demo"></p>

    </body>
</html>
```

I want to work with "detailed" variable on java class.

How can I send it?
maybe create javaScript object and import variable, such as: html.getVariables("detailes");

thanks.

Comment: Question not clear. can you explain more. what did u mean by: I want to work with "detailed" variable on java class.

Comment: You should submit your form to a java servlet to process the data or call a java web service to process the data...

Comment: Faraj Farook - I configured variable with name "detailed" (for example), on java script function, this variable save the information from user, I want to send this variable to queue, from java class.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I send it? maybe create javaScript object and import variable,
>   such as: html.getVariables("detailes");

No you cant do that you need to understand the difference between client side language(runs on the browser) and server side lanuage(runs on servers).

Your server side java code is compiled and deployed before you call any js function on client side so you cant just use the js variable in java.Instead what you need is to create a new request say post request or ajax call to hit server side code and pass the variable.